# How to persist only month and year in database in spring boot and jpa

Tags: html, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

I have a question, I have 1 input of the month/year type and I'm just trying to get this information in my database but I'm getting the following error:

```
Fri Jul 22 11:56:43 BRT 2022
```

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='fatura'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'fatura' on field 'mesReferencia': rejected value [2022-05]; codes [typeMismatch.fatura.mesReferencia,typeMismatch.mesReferencia,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [fatura.mesReferencia,mesReferencia]; arguments []; default message [mesReferencia]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'mesReferencia'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-05'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-05]]

below is my class model:

```
public class Fatura {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


@Column(name = "mes_referencia")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE, pattern = "yyyy, mm")
private LocalDate mesReferencia;
```

*accessor methods are included in the class*

**below is my input in the view**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
                                <label for="mesRef">Mês Referência:</label>
                                <input type="month" th:field="*{mesReferencia}" pattern="yyyy-MM" class="form-control" id="mesRef">
                            </div>
```

**how do i solve this problem?**

Comment: A `LocalDate` requires sufficient information for the year, the month and the day of month (or year and day of year). So `2022-05` is missing the day of month. You can use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html). (See also the related guidance in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73041696/12567365) regarding data storage for dates, in case that may be relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to model mesReferencia as a java.time.YearMonth. JPA doesn't have direct support for YearMonth but [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) does. See [this](https://prateek-ashtikar512.medium.com/how-to-store-java-time-yearmonth-as-integer-or-date-via-hibernate-types-library-7c5fe519ad7f) for more information on how to use Hibernate Types. If you aren't free to use Hibernate Types or you are not free to change the database column type then you would need
a custom converter that maps a LocalDate to your database column. A good example of this can be found [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/java-yearmonth-jpa-hibernate/).

Comment: thanks, with the references I managed to solve my problem